# jQuery multi level selector for hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have a multi level menu structured like this:

```
 <div id="outer_div">    
    <div id="menu_liv0" class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="125" data-liv="0">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="184" data-liv="0">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="240" data-liv="0">text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="menu_liv1" class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="430" data-liv="1">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="307" data-liv="1">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="652" data-liv="1">text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="menu_liv2" class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="410" data-liv="2">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="174" data-liv="2">text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="921" data-liv="2">text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to handle the hover event of li (or a) to display the second level of the menu but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried both this way and the children("li").children("a") method without any success.

```
$("#menu_liv0 > ul > li").on("mouseenter", function(){
    //function that populates the second level of the menu goes here
    $("#menu_liv1").css("display", "block");            
});
$("#menu_liv0 > ul > li").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $("#menu_liv1").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: can you explain what about `liv1` and 2?

Comment: looks like you have three single level menus to me

Comment: anyway you can use just css :hover to make multilevel hover menu

Comment: @rerich I already use css hover to change the background of divs but I also need to dinamically generate menu_liv1 when hovering a <li> of menu_liv0 and to generate menu_liv2 when hovering a <li> of menu_liv1.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I use liv0, liv1 and liv2 as a three level menu where liv0 is the lowest level, and liv2 is the highest one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the "on" to "live".
i had done a small example,Please look into this
https://jsbin.com/yeliqoroje/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please can you point to an authoritative documentation that says `live` method is preferred over the `.on()`?

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Just to know: what's the difference between .on() and .live() ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try

```
$(".menu ul li").hover(function(){
  $( this ).closest("menu").next().show();
}, function(){
  $( this ).closest("menu").next().hide();
});
```

This will ensure that when you hover on one menu item then next one will appear and so on.

**Edit:**

Looks like you are binding event to elements which don't exists at the time of event binding

Try this

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".menu ul li", function(){
  $( this ).closest("menu").next().show();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".menu ul li", function(){
  $( this ).closest("menu").next().hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.This only seems to work on ul $(".menu ul") but it doesn't work on <li>.

Comment: @dubi0s can you elaborate on `but it doesn't work on <li>`?

Comment: In my case using $(".menu ul li").hover() doesn't work but for some reason $(".menu ul").hover() works fine (but it's useless to me because I need the hover event on <li>)

Comment: Try one level deeper and include `a` as well

Comment: It still doesn't work. Probably I'm doing something wrong. However I solved my issue using .live() instead of .on(), as suggested by rav .